# How to make a stretching effect (clothes or jelly) on a custom picture on js

Tags: javascript, game-physics, pixi.js

I need to do something like the effect of stretching (clothes effect or jelly) the image so that it stretches for the mouse when you click on some part of it. I use js, pixi.js. I saw the matter js library, but probably in this case, it does not quite fit.

Here is a sample video of what to do: https://youtu.be/4uE0rjYqMWw

The main thing is to implement a similar mechanic.

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: you sure this is 2d and not 3d? Pixi.js is mainly 2d graphics library